Provision/instantiate a VM using pre-built templates versus build/provision from scratch
My systems engineering team is promoting building up a VM template (to include architecture, OS, networking, middleware services (tomcat, jboss, etc.) and possibly some 1st party services & apps), and then deploying at need from that template using parameterized configuration values for differentiation. They are using VCenter and Ansible for this, with an on-prem data center.
I've never encountered this model before.
Other teams I've worked with have always provisioned VMs from baser VM templates (architecture & OS only) and then layered on networking and then middleware services & configuration as needed & specified when the server instantiation was requested.
Has anyone else encountered the use of a more completely stacked VM template for virtual server instantiation?
How does that compare to 'ground up' instantiation?
I'm trying to make the case that 'ground up' instantiation is more agile and configurable and doesn't take significant time to instantiate.
The Systems team is making the case that periodically building up a 'gold image' template (assumably each morning) and configuring the template at instantiation is a faster instantiation and the ability to be configurable is not a hindrance.

Sorry - already voted to close this as opinion based.
But my opinion is....
Using images opens the door to:

Building instances based on templates not up to date with patches
Manual "tweaks" which might undocumented, not included in the build

The reasoning of your systems engineering team is sound. But what is the actual cost in time?
OTOH ensuring that the fresh install OR the built-from template is up to date with all patches...it may be faster to maintain a base image as a partly configured, running VM which IS always patched and clone that to get a base for building out the new VM. (which is what I've rolled out previously)
